# How do I get the 2.499858675195129e+02 number in Matlab as 2.4998?

Tags: matlab, type-conversion

I'm developing a project that I'm doing Arduino control with Matlab. I have a data set. And the values ​​in the data set are as long as `2.499858675195129e+02`. How do I get this number as `2.4998`?

Comment: Is it that you have set `format longe` and you just want to run `format`? What is the [`class`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) of those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to divide it by `100` and using `vpa`:

```
a = 2.499858675195129e+02;
a = vpa(a / 100, 5);
```

Comment: Note that you cannot have a space after `e` and before `02`. I am not sure whether the OP has written it mistakenly or this is  actually what he is getting (as a string may be?)

Comment: Thank you OmG and SardarUsama for your help. I got the result I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use round function in Matlab.

For example,

`round(a, 5)` would round to 5 decimal points.

Check their help page:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html

Comment: The OP doesn't want to round. Please see the given input and expected output

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't know if it's because of the data type. But that was not solution for me.